# Why won't Visual Studio recognize the new Filter class I added?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, filter, namespaces

I have added a new Filter class to the ASP.NET MVC Filter folder/namespace. There was one previously there as well which Visual Studio is allowing me to find through Filter.blahblahblah, however the new one won't get referenced at all... I don't understand. Do I need to do anything else to get it to find the new filter?

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Filters
{
    public class RequiresSSL : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpRequestBase req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
            HttpResponseBase res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            //Check if we're secure or not and if we're on the local box
            if (!req.IsSecureConnection && !req.IsLocal)
            {
                var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url)
                {
                    Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
                    Port = 443
                };
                res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try naming it RequiresSSLAttribute.  Using the standard convention, the compiler will expand [RequiresSSL] to RequiresSSLAttribute.